# Integrals in Plane Wave basis: $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{ikx} \, dx $

Tags: complex-integration, dirac-delta, exponential-sum

While I know

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} \, dx = 2\pi \delta(k), $$

I am wondering if someone knows how to evaluate

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{ikx} \, dx $$

? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Using MathJax is highly encouraged, and I edited your answer with an appropriate interpretation of your Mathematica code.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} \, dx = 2\pi\,  \delta(k)$$
twice with respece to $k$ we get
$$- \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{ikx} \, dx = 2\pi\,  \delta''(k)$$